Please advise how to have the pgfplotstable longtable print the headers automatically on both the first and following pages
As can be seen in the following MWE example, the headers are only printed on the following pages, not the first page. I can manually add headers by removing the comments in the pgfplotstabletypeset section, though that solution removes part of the attraction of using external data files and the automatic inclusions of headers and variable number of columns and row!
Please note, the solution must use pgfplotstable and longtables. The sample text file size has been deliberately reduced for the MWE environment.
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
AA,BB,CC,DD
1,5,30,142
2,8,80,128
2.5,4,36,128
3,5,45,130
4,6,42,155
5,8,56,161
6,3,27,146
7,6,48,159
8,3,24,155
9,1,8,153
10,5,20,51
11,1,2,204
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[
        col sep=comma,
        header=true,
        trim cells=true,
        ignore chars={"}
    ]{data.csv}\Info
    \pgfplotstableset{
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable},
    }
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,
%        header=false,
        every head row/.style={
%           output empty row,
            before row={
                    \caption{Information}\label{TabInfo}
                    \\\toprule
%                    AA & BB & CC & DD\\
%                    \midrule
                    \endfirsthead
                    \multicolumn{4}{c}{{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}%
                    \\\toprule
%                    AA & BB & CC & DD\\
            },
            after row=\midrule\endhead,
        },
        every last row/.style={
            after row=\bottomrule\\},
    ]\Info
\end{document}

